# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"- how to solve

Tags: python, json, csv

I want to convert my big json file(up to 1GB) into csv then print it.My code:

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\non_coder\\Desktop\\datasets_fldr\\layer2.json',) 
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
df = json_normalize(data['ingredients',]) 
d_file = df.to_csv('json-to-csv.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8') 
print(d_file)
```

Then the error:

```
<ipython-input-23-4a2ec3b63241> in <module>
  5 f.close()
  6 
  7 ---->df = json_normalize(data['ingredients',]) #problem indicates in this line
  8 d_file = df.to_csv('json-to-csv.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
  9 print(d_file)

 TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.
```

How should I deal with this

Comment: What happens if you remove the "," at the end of `data['ingredients',]` ?

Comment: Try to print `data`.

Comment: Judging by the error message, `data` is a list, so it makes no sense to try to index it by a string.

Answer (score 0):

```py
f = open('C:\\Users\\non_coder\\Desktop\\datasets_fldr\\layer2.json',) 
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
df = json_normalize(data['ingredients']) # <------- delete the comma here
d_file = df.to_csv('json-to-csv.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8') 
print(d_file)
```

Comment: I don't believe this will fix the problem.  The error mentions list indexes, therefore `data` is presumably a list, and you can't index a list with a string.

Comment: This will solve the `tuple` problem, then you will have to find out what is the "root" element in your JSON and if it is an array.

Comment: @MetallimaX tuple solved but still the problem in type, list indices shouldn't be str.

Comment: Can you share your JSON or at list an anonymized similar one?

Comment: I share split JSON

Comment: This is split JSON:
[
{"ingredients": [{"text": "6 ounces penne"}, {"text": "2 cups Beechers Flagship Cheese Sauce (recipe follows)"},

Comment: So your "root" element is an array (i.e. it's starting with `[`). You can either remove the external `[]` if it's still make sense or loop over the elements of the array/list then apply your logic.

Comment: As a newbie, how could I loop over the elements of the array/list

Comment: `for item in data:` and then use `item`.